# Note sync with Simplenote?

Tags: sync, tomboy, notes

Is there any note-taking app for Linux that syncs with simplenote? Are there any plans to make Tomboy do it?

Comment: AND THATS WHY IM just migrating my every day small apps to Chrome apps ... just dont kill the cloud!!

Answer (score 6):

According to the quote below, there is no plan to "officially" sync Tomboy using simplenote.

> Question: I also wonder if there are any plans to allow syncing with simplenote, since
> it seems to be kind of widespread now, especially with iOS users. It seems
> to be the single best sollution for syncing to iOS devices right now.
>
> Answer: No.  Anybody could write an add-in to do
> this, but it would lead to formatting
> loss, data loss, etc, since simplenote
> is not as "rich" as Tomboy.

*from the [tomboy mailing list](http://lists.beatniksoftware.com/htdig.cgi/tomboy-list-beatniksoftware.com/2010-December/001943.html)*

You can, however, use the following methods.

1. use the Google Chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bbgfniloleokgjiegikjpbjifiodmeba)
2. Use [Simplenotes Sync](http://fletcherpenney.net/other_projects/simplenotesync/)
3. If you use emacs, you can use [this emacs plugin](https://github.com/cefstat/simplenote.el).
4. Another option (one that I use a lot) is [notestack.me](http://notestack.me) - it is a HTML5-based program that has offline sync in Chrome, Firefox and any other web browser that supports the localStorage spec.
5. For other options, you can also take a look at the [official Simplenotes app site](http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/) downloads section.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Wine, there is a nifty free app called Resophnotes that syncs nicely with Simplenotes and works quite well in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your first question: I was also missing a Linux simplenote client, so I wrote this cross-platform (Python-Tkinter) app: https://github.com/cpbotha/nvpy

I'm using it daily, and adding features daily. At the moment it does full (foreground) syncing at startup, background per-note syncing while you work, on-demand per-note syncing and it has a neat continuous-markdown-rendering feature. The real-time regular expression searching is also quite nice.

See the readme file on the github page for current and planned features and a screenshot.

Comment: I'd just like to say thank you for this application! I spent hours and hours going through different solutions for my setup (Linux/Android) before I stumbled on simplenote and nvpy. Everything works great now and I couldn't be happier!